# NBR difference in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, differences

I want to use two NBR images(NBR1 and NBR2) for the differenced Normalized Burn Ratio (dNBR). But I can't identify the error of dNBR output.

Code snippet:

```
var NBR1 = landsat8_1.expression(
        "(NIR - SWIR2) / (NIR + SWIR2)",
        {
          SWIR2: landsat8_1.select("B7"),    //SWIR2
          NIR: landsat8_1.select("B5"),    // NIR
          BLUE: landsat8_1.select("B2")    // BLUE
        });

var NBR2 = landsat8_2.expression(
        "(NIR - SWIR2) / (NIR + SWIR2)",
        {
          SWIR2: landsat8_1.select("B7"),    //SWIR2
          NIR: landsat8_1.select("B5"),    // NIR
          BLUE: landsat8_1.select("B2")    // BLUE
        });

var dNBR = NBR1.subtract(NBR2);
```

Full code: [code.earthengine.google.com/14aaf46d74850fec158b3485c6fe702c](https://code.earthengine.google.com/14aaf46d74850fec158b3485c6fe702c)

Comment: Hi, please elaborate your question. What's the problem? Do you see an error message? Add the link to your code for debugging as well

Comment: I want to use two NBR images for the differenced Normalized Burn Ratio (dNBR)
But I don't know how to do the code
https://code.earthengine.google.com/14aaf46d74850fec158b3485c6fe702c

Comment: @willy1104 the question is closed yet, but I modified it for you. Check the code added and you will be able to identify the problem, which is just in front of your eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, always check your code and debug it. Look your code:

```
var NBR1 = landsat8_1.expression(
        "(NIR - SWIR2) / (NIR + SWIR2)",
        {
          SWIR2: landsat8_1.select("B7"),    //SWIR2
          NIR: landsat8_1.select("B5"),    // NIR
          BLUE: landsat8_1.select("B2")    // BLUE
        });

var NBR2 = landsat8_2.expression(
        "(NIR - SWIR2) / (NIR + SWIR2)",
        {
          SWIR2: landsat8_1.select("B7"),    //SWIR2
          NIR: landsat8_1.select("B5"),    // NIR
          BLUE: landsat8_1.select("B2")    // BLUE
        });
```

You are applying the same expression with the same image and storing it in two different objects. That's why the output of `dNBR` is empty. Modify it and you will have the desired output:

```
var NBR1 = landsat8_1.expression(
        "(NIR - SWIR2) / (NIR + SWIR2)",
        {
          SWIR2: landsat8_1.select("B7"),    //SWIR2
          NIR: landsat8_1.select("B5"),    // NIR
          BLUE: landsat8_1.select("B2")    // BLUE
        });

var NBR2 = landsat8_2.expression(
        "(NIR - SWIR2) / (NIR + SWIR2)",
        {
          SWIR2: landsat8_2.select("B7"),    //SWIR2 of 2nd image
          NIR: landsat8_2.select("B5"),    // NIR of 2nd image
          BLUE: landsat8_2.select("B2")    // BLUE of 2nd image
        });

var dNBR = NBR1.subtract(NBR2);
```

Please, **always check your code twice**. This is a common mistake

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback!
This is a great help and reminder to a beginner
First of all, I should do a good and complete study